# \newcommand with arguments in Kritr not working

Tags: latex, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I am quite new with Knitr, and I am trying to write my first document "importing" some "\newcommand" from my latex files.

All my "\newcommand" are processed perfectly with the exception of those with "arguments".

For instance I have added the packages I normally use in latex:

```
header-includes:
    -\usepackage{a4wide,amsmath,amsthm,epsfig,graphicx}
- \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
- \usepackage{amsfonts}
- \usepackage{graphics}
- \usepackage{subfigure}
- \usepackage{dsfont}
- \usepackage{bbm}
- \usepackage{bm}
- \usepackage{xcolor}
- \usepackage{dcolumn}
- \usepackage{pstricks,fancyhdr,fancybox}
- \usepackage{dcolumn}
- \usepackage{bm}
```

But the following does not work

```
\newcommand{\PR}[1]{\bm{P}\left\{{#1}\right\}}
```

The error is

```
output file: newfile.knit.md

"../Documents/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS newfile.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output newfile.pdf --template "C:\Users\P14814\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default-1.17.0.2.tex" --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable "geometry:margin=1in" 
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.180 \newcommand{\PR}{[}1{]}\{\bm{P}

pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"../Documents/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS newfile.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output newfile.pdf --template "C:\Users\P14814\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default-1.17.0.2.tex" --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable "geometry:margin=1in"' had status 43 
Execution halted
```

Your help is very much appreciated!!

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend you to put these commands in an external file, say, `preamble.tex`, and include it via the `includes` option.

```
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
```

See Section 3.3.7.3 of the R Markdown book: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html

Using `header-includes` is not entirely safe. Pandoc may mangle certain characters when generating the LaTeX output. If your Pandoc version is higher than 2.0 (check `rmarkdown::pandoc_version()`), you may use a raw LaTeX block to protect the LaTeX content, e.g.,

````
header-includes: |
  ```{=latex}
  \usepackage{a4wide,amsmath,amsthm,epsfig,graphicx}
  \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
  ......
  ```
````

Comment: to prevent mangling, you can also use [`{=latex} ...`](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#generic-raw-attribute)

Comment: @mb21 That is correct, but I think it requires Pandoc 2.x. The OP didn't state the RStudio version. The current RStudio release ships Pandoc 1.19.x, and the preview version ships 2.x.